# How to correctly recalculate something based on the ui after AngularJS digest?

Tags: angularjs

This seems so simple and yet frustratingly complicated.

I have a navigation type component of tabs, and to support the situation where there are too many tabs for the screen, I have an overflow menu... the markup is something like this:

```
<ul class="tabs-container">
    <li ng-repeat="feed in $ctrl.visibleFeeds track by feed.Id" ng-class="{active: feed.Id == activeTabId}">
        <a ng-href="#" ng-if="!feed.edit">
            <span ng-click="feed.edit = true">{{feed.Name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li uib-dropdown>
        <a ng-href="#" uib-dropdown-toggle role="button">
            <svg>--- menu icon ---</svg>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="feed in $ctrl.hiddenFeeds track by feed.Id">
                <a href="#">{{feed.Name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.addNewFeed()">
            <svg> --- add icon --- </svg>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully you can follow that I have two arrays bound, one for visible feeds(tabs) and one for hidden feeds.

Now to move feeds from one collection to the other I need to calculate what's too big for the screen, so I have a function to calculate what is visible.  The pseudo-code for that function is something like:

1. Make visibleTabs the whole collection.
2. Calculate how many tabs fit.
3. Move the remaining tabs to hiddenTabs collection.

The problem is I can't seem to find the 'correct' way to wait for a digest cycle to complete, so I can measure the tabs.  I can't use $scope.$apply for two reasons... 1) it might already be in a digest cycle, so I could get an error, and 2) I'm trying to avoid $scope to aid in future migration to angular 2+

I've tried a bunch of different methods, but most have come back to $timeout.  The way I understood it, if you use $timeout, it should run whatever you put inside (after any digest cycle that may already be running), and then run $apply after your function, and then continue with any promise calls you have.  So it should be something like this (according to my understanding)...

```
$timeout(() => {
    // this get's executed after current digest cycle if already running.
    this.someBinding = newValue;
}).then(() => {
    // this should execute after the original timeout func, and after a $scope.$apply() call has been made inbetween. 
    measureTheScreen();
})
```

The problem I have is the timeout function does not appear to work like that.  The "then" part is being called before $scope.$apply()
So the elements have yet to actually be rendered in the ui.

P.S. I **am** trying to figure out a more angularjs way of binding this to the viewmodel, but since it requires on the browser rendering the actual elements, I'm finding it a struggle to find a way that is really any simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in your timeout change is

1. Timeout waits for the end of the current digest
2. After the current digest, it executes `this.someBinding = value`, a new digest is queued up.
3. Then is fired immediately, and `measureTheScreen` is called before the digest queued up above is executed.
4. The digest from (2) occurs.

I've run into this problem multiple times, and I too wish there was a better way but I believe this is just a limitation of AngularJS.

How I've gotten around it in the past requires a second `$timeout`, so the THEN only occurs after the digest triggered from the first `$timeout` completes...

In your case it would be

```
//1. waits for a digest to occur
$timeout(() => {
    //2. Digest 1 occurs, code is executed
    this.someBinding = newValue;
    //3. New digest is queued up to occur
}).then(() => {
    //4. waits for digest 2 to occur
    return $timeout(() => {
        //5. Digest 2 occurs, and now I can safely execute code that depends on html being rendered in timeout 1
        measureTheScreen();
    }
});
```

So they key here is that even though your $timeout does trigger a $scope.$apply, you still need to wait for that new digest to go through using another $timeout.